# How to get current location and pass inside the tree via Inherited Widget in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-provider, inherited-widget

I am trying to share the current location of an user within the app in other routes.

My widget tree is quite extensive to keep passing the value down, so I would like to get it easier and updated in a interval of 1 minute in the widgets below.

I've tried Provider and Inherited widget but my value is null and I'm getting the error:

```
The following NoSuchMethodError was thrown building:
The getter 'currentPosition' was called on null.
Receiver: null
Tried calling: currentPosition
```

My initial class

```
class _HomeScreenState extends State<HomeScreen> {
  Placemark _currentPlaceMark;
  Position _currentPosition =
      Position(longitude: -23.708422, latitude: -46.5568553);

  initState() {
    super.initState();
    //Get the current location of user
    _determinePosition();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return CurrentPositionInherited(
      child: MaterialApp(
        debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
        title: mainTitleApp,
        theme: ThemeData(
          primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
          visualDensity: VisualDensity.adaptivePlatformDensity,
        ),
        home: Scaffold(
            drawer: CustomDrawer(),
            appBar: AppBar(
              title: Text(mainTitleApp),
            ),
            body: BodyCategoriesList()),
      ),
      currentPosition: _currentPosition,
    );
  }
```

The method I call at Init to determine the current position

```
void _determinePosition() async {
    
    var pos = await Geolocator.getCurrentPosition();
    setState(() {
      _currentPosition = pos;
    });

    placemarkFromCoordinates(pos.latitude, pos.longitude)
        .then((value) => setState(() {
              _currentPlaceMark = value.first;
            }));

}
```

My Inherited Widget

```
class CurrentPositionInherited extends InheritedWidget {
  const CurrentPositionInherited({
    Key key,
    @required this.currentPosition,
    @required Widget child,
  })  : assert(child != null),
        super(key: key, child: child);

  final Position currentPosition;

  static CurrentPositionInherited of(BuildContext context) {
    return context.dependOnInheritedWidgetOfExactType()
        as CurrentPositionInherited;
  }

  @override
  bool updateShouldNotify(CurrentPositionInherited old) =>
      currentPosition != old.currentPosition;
}
```

inside the  BodyCategoriesList() It has 2 layers of widgets that led to other routes (because I call the MaterialPageRoute to build other pages) and then I try to call the location property using this approach:

```
  Widget _buildSubtitle(RatingModel rating, BuildContext context) {
    print(CurrentPositionInherited.of(context)
        .currentPosition
        .latitude
        .toString());       
  }
```

I just want to share my current location updated in this deep widget but I couldn't achieve that and I am trying for hours!

Comment: Hi, interesting, perhaps check if the object is `null`

Comment: It may be null, but I'd like to know why is getting null..